# C++: Error "declaration expected"

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have the following cpp file, and the error "Declaration expected" is thrown in this line, pointing at "for":

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_Floats.size(); ++i)
```

The entire code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include "clsJenksBreaks.h"

using namespace std;

vector<float>m_Floats

vector<float>getJenksBreaks(const unsigned int uNumClass)
{
    //std::sort(m_Floats, m_Floats + size, std::greater<float>());

    float **mat1 = new float*[m_Floats.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_Floats.size(); ++i) 
    {
        mat1[i] = new float[iNumClass];
    }
    for (unsigned long x=0;x<uNumClass+1;x++)
    {
        for (unsigned long y=0;y<m_Floats.size()+1,y++)
        {
            mat1[x][y]=0;
        }
    }

    //I have commented out the other code that is in this function, but the error still exists.

}
```

Does anybody see where I went wrong?

Comment: you have quite some typos: missing semicolons, `iNumClass` instead of `uNumClass`. Can you copy paste what you are really trying to compile?

Comment: There are errors on several lines, but not that one. Perhaps you could post the exact code you're compiling, and the exact error messages?

Comment: The problem is extremely basic, but that alone doesn't warrant the -5 votes. He has expressed the problem clearly, given a code example, and has made effort to try to solve it himself (as indicated by the comment at the bottom). +1 to cancel out some of the negative votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon after the declaration of `m_floats`.  Try:

```
vector<float>m_Floats;
```

Answer (score 9):

There is no error on the line you indicate. The errors are:

- missing semicolon at the end of line 7 (declaration of `m_Floats`).
- missing declarations of `iNumClass` and `uNumClass` (presumably they're in the header you haven't shown us)
- comma instead of semicolon on line 20, before the for-loop incrementor.

Answer (score 2):

Possible typo,

```
 mat1[i] = new float[iNumClass];
```

should be

```
 mat1[i] = new float[uNumClass];
```